# Classifying quaternion algebras by their zeta functions

Tags: number-theory, quaternions

In Vignéras' book on quaternion algebras, she uses the properties of the zeta functions to deduce some results on the classification of quaternion algebras. The zeta function attached to a quaternion algebra $H$ over a global field $F$ (say $\mathbb Q$ to lighten notations) is related to the Dedekind zeta function by
$$\zeta_H(s/2) = \zeta_F(s) \zeta_F(1-s) \prod_{p\in \mathrm{Ram}(H)} (1-p^{1-s})$$
We know $Z_H(s)$ has a simple pole at $0$ and $1$ if $H$ is a field (in particular for $F$), and is holomorphic elsewhere. But the above finite product has a zero of order $\mathrm{Ram}(H)$ at $1$. Taking $s=1$ above, we get two poles from $\zeta_K$ and this zero, hence a zero of order $\mathrm{Ram}(H)-2$.

How then do we deduce the *equivalence* that $H=M_2(F)$ if and only if $H_v=M_2(F_v)$ at each place $v$ of $F$?

I understand that if $Ram(H)=\varnothing$, then there is a new pole at $1/2$ and we cannot have a field. But otherwise, we get a zero and there is no obstruction for $H$ to be a field (but no obligation either!)

Comment: Are you aware of [this book](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/quat-book.pdf)?

Comment: I don't understand many parts of your question. Your formula for $\zeta_H$ looks like a theorem not the definition. What is $Z_H$. With "$H$ is a field" you meant a division algebra? $H\cong M_2(F)$ iff each $H_v \cong  M_2(F_v)$ probably relies on several previous results. $M_2(F_v)$ appears at the "non-ramified" $v$.

Comment: The $M_2(k)$ versus division algebra stuff should have to do something with if the norm quadratic form is isotropic, and the local-global theorem would follow from the one for quadratic forms.

Comment: Don't you know the classification of CSAs by this point in Vigneras?  A quaternion algebra must be either M_2(F) or division.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for the reference, he rewrites indeed some sections of Vignéras' book in a more modern fashion. However, he does not address the classification by means of the zeta functions I think, having a quick look

Comment: @reuns (and @Kimball) The form of $\zeta_H$ is indeed not a definition, it is a theorem. However it does not depend on the global classification, but indeed on the classification of local ones. Vignéras emphasizes (Chap 3, Sec 3) that she wants to illustrate how this zeta function allows to deduce the global classification that reuns quote: $H$ is $M_2(F)$ iff it is so locally.