# Hasse-Minkowski principle and square theorems

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms, quadratic-residues

This is a question in the same spirit than [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4082836/classifying-quaternion-algebras-by-their-zeta-functions), trying to prove algebraic number theoretic statements from zeta functions. I want to prove the Hasse-Minkowski principle for quadratic forms in two variables. Let $q(x, y) = qx^2+by^2$.

The Hasse-Minkowski principle is equivalent to the square theorem: $a\in K^2$ iff $a\in K_v^2$ for all place $v$ of the base field $K$.

Let $L = K(\sqrt{a})$ at extension of $K$ of degree 1 or 2. If it is everywhere isomorphic to $K_v \oplus K_v$, the associated zeta function would have a double pole and hence $L$ would not be a field (which is not).

Why is $L\simeq K_v \oplus K_v$ equivalent to $a \in K_v^2$?

Comment: It makes no sense to ask if $L$, a number field, is isomorphic to $K_v \oplus K_v$: one is countable and the other is not. If you meant to write $L_v$ then explain what that means ($v$ is a place of $K$, not $L$). If you meant to write $K_v \otimes_K L$ then write that.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal polynomial of $a^{1/2}$ is $x^2-a\in K[x]$.

$a$ is not a square in $K_v$ iff $x^2-a\in K_v[x]$ is irreducible iff $$K_v\otimes_K K(a^{1/2})\cong K_v\otimes_K K[x]/(x^2-a)\cong K_v[x]/(x^2-a)$$ is a field.

If $a=b^2\in K_v$ is a square then $x^2-a=(x-b)(x+b)$ and $$K_v\otimes_K K(a^{1/2})\cong K_v[x]/((x-b)(x+b))\cong K_v[x]/(x-b) \times K_v[x]/(x+b) \cong K_v\times K_v$$

(isomorphisms as rings and $K_v$ algebras)